# Inverse image of sets of Lebesgue measure zero.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a measurable function from an Euclidean space to the reals. Is it true that the inverse image of every set of measure zero is also measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not! See Remark 1.3.10 in Terrence Tao's Intro to Measure Theory--found here https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf